# Automated login and screen lock

Tags: auto-login

My computer only has a single user that is used for normal log in.

On boot, it would be convenient of the system would log in that user automatically, and then optionally, lock the screen, such as by launching a password protected screen saver.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Set your user for automatic login in `System Settings` -> `User Accounts` -> `Automatic Login` (you will need to press the "unlock" button and enter your password before you can change the automatic login setting).

The command `gnome-screensaver-command -l` will cause the screen to be immediately locked, which can probably be added to your autostart items.

Using `gedit` (or other text editor of choice), create `/home/USERNAME/.config/autostart/screen_lock.desktop` with contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Lock Screensaver
Exec=gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

And hopefully it will automatically login and then lock the screen.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 does not recognize those desktop entries in my case..

Comment: Checkout how to add a startup script here:

Comment: First install gnome-screensaver by this command: sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with Gnome 3.28.2 and this worked for me.
Set a user to auto-login, either via the GUI or by editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.
On the desktop, click on Show Applications, type in "Start" and you'll see the "Startup Applications Preferences", open it, click on Add, give it whatever Name and Comment you'd like and put the following in the Command input:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
```

On re-boot, it will auto-login and immediately lock the screen for whatever user you set up in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.

Comment: I was skeptical, but it worked like a charm.

Comment: This works and should be the accepted solution

Comment: Thanks works for me, and save the answer

Answer (score 3):

What you ask is almost a normal setup. During installation you get asked to insert a password and can choose to have that user log in automatically. This image shows the checkbox as `off` (You can not use automatic log in with an encrypted home).

[image]

After install you can still set this at the accounts settings:

[image]

The screen lock is by default set to ask for a password. Have a look at this topic for more information: [How do I disable the screensaver/lock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177348/how-do-i-disable-the-screensaver-lock-in-12-04) on where to find it. The setting where you can do this looks like this:

[image]

It is about not setting the lock but you just have to set it the other way.

Comment: With this setup the user will be logged on automatically with their computer unlocked vulnerable to attacks. What OP is asking is how to login and lock the screen  automatically at the same time after boot.

Comment: @denysonique he said "optionally lock the screen" so this is a user discussion that can not be automated ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but this is the best option:

#### Set your user for automatic login

```
echo "AutomaticLoginEnable=True" | sudo tee -a /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
echo "AutomaticLogin=$(whoami)" | sudo tee -a /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Or change in `Settings` -> `Users` -> `Automatic Login`

#### Write a script

`gnome-screensaver` can do the job but we have to make shure its available when the machine runs the code. To get it, create a script with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

duration()
{
    echo "$(( SECONDS - start ))"
}

iscrazy()
{
    (( $(duration) > 60 ))
}

state()
{
    /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command -q
}

isactive()
{
    ! grep -q "inactive" <<< "$(state)"
}

start=$SECONDS

/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver &

until isactive || iscrazy
do
    /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command -l
done

echo "$(state) and it took $(duration) seconds"
```

This will attempt to lock the screen until it succeeds or spends more time than usual.

Make shure that execution is enabled on file permissions with

```
chmod +x <pathtoscript>
```

or checking "Allow executing file as program" by right-clicking and going to `Properties` -> `Permissions`

I recommend you run it before the next step

#### Place it between the startup applications

```
echo "[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Lock Screensaver
Exec=<pathtoscript>" > ~/.config/autostart/screen_lock.desktop
```

or add manually in "Startup Applications" (`gnome-session-properties`)

#### Notes

Works with Ubuntu and has been tested on a Pop! _OS 20.04

You have to install the needed packages as `gnome-screensaver`

Remember to change `<pathtoscript>` with the path to the script you created

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of answers to this already old question but none of them where satisfactory for me. Here is how to do it using a systemd service.

**Set your user for automatic login**

This can be easyly done by changing it in `Settings` -> `Users` -> `Automatic Login`

**Create a Systemd service**

Create a file in `/home/<username>/.local/share/systemd/user/` that is named in the format`<name>.service` containing the following code:

```
[Unit]
Description=Lock screen on login
After=graphical.target gnome-session.target
Requires=gnome-session.target

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.gnome.ScreenSaver
ExecStart=dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver or>
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

The crux here is the `After=` and `Requires=` to be set to the display manager that you are using, here it is `gnome-session` for instance.

Now all you need to do is run `systemctl --user enable <name>.service` to enable the service and lock the screen on login.
It can be easily disabled by running `systemctl --user disable <name>.service`

Comment: doesn't work for me (Ubuntu 20.04) 
dbus-send[10722]: Must use org.mydomain.Interface.Method notation, no dot in "or>"
systemd[1362]: lock.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1362]: lock.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1362]: Failed to start Lock screen on login.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that use a KDE based system, follow these instructions:

***Automatic Login Required First***

This can be easily done by changing it in `Settings` -> `Startup and Shutdown` -> `Login Screen` -> `Automatically Login`

***Screen Saver Command for KDE***

This is the Qt command you would add to startup; as an application:

```
qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.Lock
```

Note: `Settings` -> `Startup and Shutdown` -> `Autostart` -> `Add Application`