# How to unlock the lock-screen with mouse only

Tags: mouse, password, lock-screen, unlock

I use the automatic login and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181265/automated-login-and-screen-lock/181271#181271) method to lock the screen of my Ubuntu 18.04.3. 90% of the time it works as a media player and I controll it with the remote mouse. And I have to use the screen keyboard tweak every time to input the password to unlock it. if there's any way I could use a mouse only for this procedure? Maybe there's a graphical password just like on a mobile phone or a screensaver which would contain such functionality.

Comment: Because you have automatic login, it seems strange to me that you have it lock and require a password.  I use a pc as a media player too, and have it blank screen only, so mouse movement wakes it (no lock).  My files are accessed from shares, but since I only give the device read access to certain directories (no write to anything given the autologin) I see no reason for any password.

Comment: One of the reasons for  automatic login is VNC. It doesn't work before login in 18.04 default mode (https://askubuntu.com/a/1044081/1018915). And I somehow must restrict the accses to my screen after start.

Comment: You could disable the lock screen: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048774/disabling-lock-screen-18-04/1064704#1064704