# Automatic screen lock on startup is blocked by an application

Tags: lock-screen, screensaver

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and is trying to set up my system so it will log in my single user automatically but employ a locked screensaver on startup to ensure security.

I have followed the solution here [Automated login and screen lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181265/automated-login-and-screen-lock) and created the file ~/.config/autostart/screen_lock.desktop with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Lock Screensaver
Exec=gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

Upon startup I am logged in automatically but I get the desktop message: *Unable to lock: Lock was blocked by an application*

Running

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

manually in the terminal works fine.
I have looked in journalctl, but can only seem to find the same error as shown on the desktop: *gnome-shell[1518]: error: Unable to lock: Lock was blocked by an application*

Besides the screensaver I have *im-launc* and *SSH Key Agent* as startup applications, and I have some crontab jobs running a Python and a bash script, but this should all be background stuff and I can't figure out what is causing the problem. I can see other people have lock-screen problems with full-screen applications and virtual machines, but this is right on startup without (as far as I can tell) problematic applications running.

Any ideas to figure out what is causing the issue or workarounds?

Comment: mine is blocked by the keyring asking for the unlock password which is coming from Firefox

Answer (score 2):

If it works from the CLI, then this is probably a race condition, so you could try putting a sleep in front of the command.

I'd try `sleep 60;gnome-screensaver-command -l` to start with, to make sure that the login processes have all completed. If that works then you can try `sleep 1`, and then experiment to find a trade off between it working and speed of lock.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in order to put multiple commands like that in the `Exec` field, you need to do it like this: `bash -c "sleep 1;gnome-screensaver-command -l"`

Answer (score 1):

I was previously running 18.04 and had this working using [Automated login and screen lock](https://askubuntu.com/a/1094340) but once upgrading to 20.04, ran into the same problem as the OP. The screensaver works when manually triggered via CLI and Super+L, but not after autologin via the autostarter (got the same *blocked by application* error, or sometimes nothing at all).

Using @lcd's idea, I was not able to get

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Lock Screensaver
Exec=sleep 60;gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

working with entries in `~/.config/autostart/`. It doesn't seem to trigger, with no evidence of it in `journalctl`.

What did work was autostarting a bash script that called `gnome-screensaver-command -l`. I tried calling it without the `sleep` command resulted in the following entries in `journalctl`, suggesting that @lcd was right in that there some sort of race condition:

```
Jan 20 14:37:47 PC gnome-screensav[1735]: unable to send message: Timeout was reached
Jan 20 14:37:47 PC gnome-screensav[1735]: Did not receive a reply from the screensaver.
```

So my current workaround is:

`/home/user/.config/autostart/bootscript1.sh.desktop`
containing:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Lock Screensaver
Exec=/home/user/keeps/bootscript1.sh
```

where `bootscript1.sh` is

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 1 
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

Comment: You can avoid the need to create an actual bash script by setting `Exec` to `bash -c "sleep 1;gnome-screensaver-command -l"`. It's also worth mentioning that while `sleep 1` usually works, it occasionally didn't, so if it doesn't work for you try `sleep 2` or higher values.