# How to start the teamviewer service before login?

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer

Suppose that there are two pc :pc-A and pc-B,both of them installed teamviewer(version 15.13.6).
First i boot pc-A,pc-B,no name and password inputted in pc-A,instead name and password inputted in pc-B,i login pc-B,the below is a screenshot for pc-A.
[image]

At this time , i can't input name and password in pc-A from pc-B via teamviewer,because that teamviewer service have not started in pc-A.

I want to set teamviewer service started before login pc-A.
Here is my try:

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/remote-desktop.service    
[Unit]    
Description=remote-desktop
After=network.target
    
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer
KillMode=process

    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

sudo systemctl reload remote-desktop.service
sudo systemctl enable remote-desktop.service
```

The remote-desktop.service can't be started at boot time until login.

```
● remote-desktop.service - remote-desktop
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/remote-desktop.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Sat 2021-01-23 16:33:58 CST; 3min 3s ago
  Process: 871 ExecStart=/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 871 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
      CPU: 922ms

Jan 23 16:33:33  systemd[1]: Started remote-desktop.
Jan 23 16:33:36  teamviewer[871]: Init...
Jan 23 16:33:37  teamviewer[871]: xprop:  unable to open display ''
Jan 23 16:33:37  teamviewer[871]: CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes
Jan 23 16:33:37  teamviewer[871]: Checking setup...
Jan 23 16:33:37  teamviewer[871]: Launching TeamViewer ...
Jan 23 16:33:37  teamviewer[871]: Launching TeamViewer GUI ...
Jan 23 16:33:58  systemd[1]: remote-desktop.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Jan 23 16:33:58  systemd[1]: remote-desktop.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 23 16:33:58  systemd[1]: remote-desktop.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

Reboot pc-A and test, the name and password still can't input from pc-B via teamviewer.
And it is no use to set something in teamviewer's option.
[image]

My teamvierwer is the free version,there is no option such as `Full access control when a partner is connecting to the Windows logon screen` in my version,maybe you can introduce some other free remote control software (important:pay no money ) which can start before logoning the `login screen` .I accept it as a solution too when you have done,give the 500 bounty point.
Sum up:after remotely waking my pc,how can input account name and passwrod remotely,i can't do it with teamviewer.

How to fix it?

Comment: Silly question, but did you change your `remote-desktop.service` to be executable? ⇢ `sudo chmod +x /etc/systemd/system/remote-desktop.service`

Comment: Please make the experiment with teamviewer and post your conclusion.

Comment: @Matigo `/etc/systemd/system/remote-desktop.service` or any other **systemd** unit file need not to be made executable like that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying and investigating the situation you have described in your post, the issue seems to be that this version of TeamViewer is unable to start an X server session which is needed for TeamViewer to work.

So you can enable **automatic login** on pc-A and it will work. Have a look at [Automated login and screen lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181265/automated-login-and-screen-lock) If you need privacy and want the screen locked.

However, you do need to enable **Start TeamViewer with system** and set **Personal Password** under options in TeamViewer on pc-A then reboot first for that to work.

---

An alternative solution to remotely login and start X server session for TeamViewer to work is to install `xrdp` on pc-A like so:

```
sudo apt install xrdp
```

Then, make sure the `xrdp` service is enabled and started ( it usually is ).

After that from pc-B run `remmina` like so:

```
remmina
```

Then, enter the pc-A's IP in the `remmina` GUI and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

`remmina` is most likely already installed on your system but if you need, install it like so:

```
sudo apt install remmina
```

---

**Notice:**

You can connect to `xrdp` by IP / Host-name only and if the two PCs are not on the same local network, you might find free dynamic DNS services like [no-ip](https://www.noip.com/) and others helpful.

Comment: This is a solid solution. Nice 

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer automatically created this for me, /etc/systemd/system/teamviewerd.service.

It looks a little bit different than yours.
And it works for me.

```
[Unit]
Description = TeamViewer remote control daemon
After = network.target network-online.target dbus.service
Wants = network-online.target
Requires = dbus.service

[Service]
Type = forking
PIDFile = /var/run/teamviewerd.pid
ExecStart = /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/teamviewerd -d
Restart = on-abort
StartLimitInterval = 60
StartLimitBurst = 10

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Comment: I'm saying it works for me.

Comment: With the edit the answer makes more sense.