# RDP unresponsive on my Ubuntu

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm trying to remote, RDP, my Ubuntu Desktop version 20.04 LTS from my Windows 10 machine. The Ubuntu machine is use primarily for my Plex server. So it's a standalone machine without a screen and a keyboard/mouse. I tried everything, from TeamViewer to VLC to Windows RDP.

The connection to the machine is not the problem, but when I connect with either software mention earlier nothing is moving on the screen it's like frozen. The only time it's actually working is if I plug a screen on the machine. Now TeamViewer, VLC and RDP are working like a charm. I don't want a screen on the PC since it's in a location where I have minimal space. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to install Ubuntu Server for that to work?

Comment: I'm confused why you need a screen or RDP or VLC at all. Plex uses a 
*web based* interface. You administer the server remotely using SSH. You administer Plex remotely using a web browser. Are you trying to run Gnome merely to administer the server? Did you misconfigure Plex to localhost only?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start the teamviewer service before login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309540/how-to-start-the-teamviewer-service-before-login)

Comment: Yeah I get your confusion here. I'm pretty new in the Linux world but I found, I think, and answer to my question using that post : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033436/how-to-use-ubuntu-18-04-on-vnc-without-display-attached.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Ubuntu 18.04 on VNC without display attached?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033436/how-to-use-ubuntu-18-04-on-vnc-without-display-attached)