# Easy remote control for Ubuntu

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, remote-access

All our workstations are Ubuntu 18.04.5. Currently, to connect from home, employees use X2GO.

Problem is, there are complains about it crashing, getting stuck, being un-intuitive, and not having the ability to connect from home to the same session from home. It also requires ubuntu MATE which is just the worst.

I tried setting up xrdp but it just gives me a blue screen, and I was told that it was incompatible with ldap users (but i assume pam could fix that).

Does anyone know an easy remote control for users to connect from home, that would also allow opening the same session from work/home? Preferably one that would work with the regular ubuntu but other distribution are also welcome.

Thanks ahaed!

Comment: You could use [TeamViewer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1310430/968501) or [xrdp](https://askubuntu.com/a/1311346/968501)