# How can I disable all locking in 14.10?

Tags: security, 14.10, lock-screen

I don't want the machine to prompt for password on resume from suspend, I don't want the machine to lock after a certain period of inactivity.  At the moment, I only want it to lock

a) when it boots up the first time and 
b) when I explicitly tell it to do so.  I've tried:

- toggling everything in System Settings (security settings, power settings, display/desktop settings, etc)
- unity tweak tool
- toggling org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
- commenting out LOCK_SCREEN in `/etc/default/acpi-support`

nothing works: if I leave the machine for more than `org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay`, it locks; if I `xset dpms force off`, it locks; if I close the lid & suspend, it locks.  Of course, with disable-lock-screen set to true, CTRL+ALT+L just blanks the screen momentarily and then does NOT lock.

I'm contemplating turning on auto-login for my user, and then "locking" by trying to bring up a "switch user" screen or something; but really, I'm hoping somebody

a) can help me figure out how to get the desired behavior; or 
b) explain why it doesn't work any more (my 12.04 laptop does exactly what I want & honors the settings in the System Settings)

Comment: To disable the screen lock, you can use the command "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false" you can also refer the solution available in the link http://askubuntu.com/questions/177348/how-do-i-disable-the-screensaver-lock

Comment: org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled is already set to 'false'