# hard crash on gnome x login after 15.10 upgrade

Tags: gnome, intel-nuc

I recently updated to 15.10 and I am running Ubuntu Gnome on a Celeron NUC DCCP847DYE. NUC has latest BIOS. The machine boots up to Gnome user list login screen, but any login action causes a complete hard crash & reboot.

I have tried sessions in Gnome, Gnome Classic and System Default

dmesg does not show anything. syslog (via SSH from another host) shows:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 15.10 (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-16-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Sun Nov  1 09:16:07 2015 from 192.168.1.6
superusername@problemhost:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
[sudo] password for superusername: 
Nov  1 09:16:59 problemhost ntpd[2485]: Listen normally on 3 eth1 192.168.1.3 UDP 123
Nov  1 09:16:59 problemhost ntpd[2485]: Listen normally on 4 eth1 192.168.1.22 UDP 123
Nov  1 09:16:59 problemhost ntpd[2485]: Listen normally on 5 wlan0 192.168.1.15 UDP 123
Nov  1 09:16:59 problemhost ntpd[2485]: Listen normally on 6 lo ::1 UDP 123
Nov  1 09:16:59 problemhost ntpd[2485]: Listen normally on 7 eth1 fe80::c23f:d5ff:fe60:5875 UDP 123
Nov  1 09:16:59 problemhost ntpd[2485]: Listen normally on 8 wlan0 fe80::fef8:aeff:feac:ed1f UDP 123
Nov  1 09:16:59 problemhost ntpd[2485]: peers refreshed
Nov  1 09:16:59 problemhost ntpd[2485]: Listening on routing socket on fd #25 for interface updates
Nov  1 09:17:01 problemhost CRON[2490]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov  1 09:17:03 problemhost sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/superusername is already mounted
Nov  1 09:17:46 problemhost kernel: [  124.641568] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:c4:04:15:61:76:53:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Nov  1 09:17:53 problemhost kernel: [  131.285545] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:fb:b8:27:eb:25:29:cd:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.25 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Nov  1 09:17:57 problemhost gdm-password]: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/superusername is already mounted
Nov  1 09:17:57 problemhost systemd[1]: Started Session c3 of user superusername.
Nov  1 09:17:57 problemhost console-kit-daemon[1719]: (process:2524): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Nov  1 09:17:58 problemhost acpid: client connected from 2526[0:0]
Nov  1 09:17:58 problemhost acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Nov  1 09:17:58 problemhost org.freedesktop.systemd1[2530]: ** (process:2602): WARNING **: Could not connect to cgmanager: Could not connect: No such file or directory
Nov  1 09:17:58 problemhost org.freedesktop.systemd1[2530]: ** (process:2602): CRITICAL **: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'.  Quitting.
Nov  1 09:17:58 problemhost org.a11y.Bus[2629]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Nov  1 09:17:58 problemhost org.a11y.Bus[2629]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Nov  1 09:17:58 problemhost org.a11y.atspi.Registry[2703]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Nov  1 09:17:59 problemhost kernel: [  137.697141] Valid eCryptfs headers not found in file header region or xattr region, inode 4985892
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig[2629]: (display-config-daemon:2776): libupower-glib-WARNING **: No 'CanSuspend' property
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig[2629]: ** (display-config-daemon:2776): WARNING **: Unable to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost rtkit-daemon[2265]: Successfully made thread 2792 of process 2792 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost rtkit-daemon[2265]: Supervising 3 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost org.gnome.ScreenSaver[2629]: ** (gnome-screensaver:2771): WARNING **: Couldn't get presence status: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: gnome-session[2751]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file indicator-china-weather.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file indicator-china-weather.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost rtkit-daemon[2265]: Supervising 3 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost rtkit-daemon[2265]: Successfully made thread 2795 of process 2792 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost rtkit-daemon[2265]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost bluetoothd[1022]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.102 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost bluetoothd[1022]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.102 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost bluetoothd[1022]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: gnome-session[2751]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file indicator-china-weather.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file indicator-china-weather.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: gnome-session[2751]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file gnome-fallback-mount-helper.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file gnome-fallback-mount-helper.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: gnome-session[2751]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file gnome-sound-applet.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file gnome-sound-applet.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost dbus[987]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service'
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost systemd[1]: Starting Locale Service...
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost dbus[987]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost systemd[1]: Started Locale Service.
Nov  1 09:18:00 problemhost gnome-session[1864]: (gnome-settings-daemon:2215): color-plugin-WARNING **: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Failed to open file '/home/superusername/.local/share/icc/edid-b84a4f70077f91348801ffefec734951.icc': Permission denied
Nov  1 09:18:01 problemhost org.gnome.ScreenSaver[2629]: ** Message: Lost the name, shutting down.
Nov  1 09:18:01 problemhost kernel: [  139.827496] Valid eCryptfs headers not found in file header region or xattr region, inode 4980834
Nov  1 09:18:01 problemhost org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources4[2629]: (evolution-source-registry:2843): e-data-server-WARNING **: e_module_load_all_in_directory: Error opening directory '/usr/lib/evolution-data-server/credential-modules': No such file or directory
Nov  1 09:18:02 problemhost dbus[987]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service'
Nov  1 09:18:02 problemhost systemd[1]: Starting Location Lookup Service...
Nov  1 09:18:02 problemhost dbus[987]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
Nov  1 09:18:02 problemhost systemd[1]: Started Location Lookup Service.
Nov  1 09:18:02 problemhost org.gnome.OnlineAccounts[2629]: goa-daemon-Message: goa-daemon version 3.14.2 starting
Nov  1 09:18:02 problemhost org.freedesktop.Telepathy.AccountManager[2629]: (process:2856): mcd-WARNING **: Not sure what the type of 'mc-account-name' is, assuming string
Nov  1 09:18:02 problemhost org.gtk.Private.AfcVolumeMonitor[2629]: Volume monitor alive
Nov  1 09:18:02 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG: No permission to trigger offline updates: Polkit.Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
Nov  1 09:18:02 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: (uint32 1,)
Nov  1 09:18:02 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: Entering running state
Nov  1 09:18:03 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: ** (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:2901): WARNING **: Unable to register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject
Nov  1 09:18:03 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: Cannot register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject
Nov  1 09:18:03 problemhost dbus[987]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Nov  1 09:18:03 problemhost systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Nov  1 09:18:04 problemhost dbus[987]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Nov  1 09:18:04 problemhost systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Nov  1 09:18:04 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: (gnome-shell:2808): Gjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: could not get remote objects for service org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Smartcard: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard was not provided by any .service files
Nov  1 09:18:04 problemhost gnome-session[2751]: _proxyInvoker/asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/overrides/Gio.js:83
```

Comment: Not sure but I think the gnome screensaver / screen off stuff is broken in 15.10

http://askubuntu.com/questions/177348/how-do-i-disable-the-screensaver-lock

I just tried disabling it crossing my fingers and hoping it works.

I've been able to login and use ctrl + alt + f1 but restarting the `lightdm` doesnt have the magic effect it once did