# How can I turn off the screen saver?

Tags: unity, screensaver

- I **want** my physical monitor to turn off (standby mode) after some minutes.
- I **do not** want to run any fancy idle graphics on the display - just show my apps or desktop, then simply turn OFF. Just *off.*

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/177353/5786) seems to be the closest match, and yet it doesn't help me. My settings are exactly these, and this is Ubuntu 15.04:
[image]

I'm getting the impression that my insanely high CPU usage on idle by `compiz` is caused by this. I've struggled with this compiz problem for *years* and it's annoying. My computer is a monster, but compiz is crippling it, and it's loudest and hottest *when it's idle!* Help!