# How to disable account logoff when closing lid of laptop

Tags: 16.04, suspend, laptop

I am trying to set up a home cloud server on my old Ubuntu laptop However when i leave it running and close the lid of my laptop of course I get logged out and the process stops.

Is there a way to either completely disable the logoff when closing the lid OR a way to make sure the process keeps running even when I am logged off?

Any help is gratefully received.

/Mark

Comment: What's the value for `HandleLidSwitch` in file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to ... completely disable the logoff when closing the lid ...?

Which operation system do you use exactly?
For me with ubuntu 16.04 LTS I could handle the logoff issue with following standard system settings:

- Turn off the Lock 
  system settings > Brightness & Lock > Lock: OFF
  ([Details here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177348/how-do-i-disable-the-screensaver-lock%22TITEL%22))
- Maybe in addition you need to switch on "[Automatic Login](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html)" for your user:
    system settings > User Accounts > Automatic Login: On

Comment: this seems to have done the trick...I had missed the Brightness and lock - OFF

Comment: But if I want the lock functionality but not the logoff?

Comment: Also, the asker asks for the computer to just continue working - not related to related to any lock or not lock. Just continue running on lid closed.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04, and maybe even on previous versions, you can disable logoff going to **Preferences -> Power Management** and set to "Do nothing" on "When laptop lid is closed".

[image]

Comment: I dont have this open in 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Using `Tweaks` how described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-closelid.html.en) helped me:

1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Tweaks.
2. Click Tweaks to open the application.
3. Select the General tab.
4. Switch the Suspend when laptop lid is closed switch to off.
5. Close the Tweaks window.