# How to disable screensaver lock?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, lock-screen, screensaver

I want that my monitor turns off when I am inactive for a while, but I do not want that I am prompted for a password when I revoke my pc. In Ubuntu 16.04 it was possible to disable the lock but still enable the screensaver as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/177353/247771).

In Ubuntu 18.04 I entered the following in terminal:

```
dconf-editor
```

and disabled `ubuntu-lock-on-suspend`:

[image]

However, since I made this change, my monitor never suspends anymore. I tried restart but it didn't help.

Any ideas how I can disable lock but still enable suspend mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just realized lock and suspend are two different things in Ubuntu 18.04.

One may disable the lock here:
[image]

But still enable suspend here:
[image]